# JS event handlers behaviours different in incognito mode

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a class which should save some datas when browser is about to close:

```
class Foo {
  session;

  init() {
    window.addEventListener('unload', this.saveSession.bind(this));
    this.session = {};
  }

  public saveSession() {
    console.log(this.session);  
  }
}
```

Now, for some reason, the `session` property saved by the event handler is always the empty object, no matter what change I apply to it (new props to the same obj, a whole new object etc).

The weird thing is: it works in localhost, it works in test machine in incognito mode, it doesn't work in test machine in normal mode.

How is this possible?

Comment: What code do you actually run?

Comment: @VLAZ https://test.shootbook.app/app look for "session.service.ts". The use case is: first time you come inside the app, tutorial should appear. Second time, no.

Comment: Please put a [example] in a StackBlitz. Is it possible you have a global error/exception handler that is swallowing errors?

Comment: Session storage does not work in private browsing mode. Testing for this is also one of the ways you can detect private browsing mode.